# Convergence of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\alpha > 0$.

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, u_n = 1- \cos{\frac{1}{n^\alpha}}$$

How do I know when the series $\sum u_n$ converges depending on the value of $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Taylor expand maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write:
$$
   u_n = 1 - \cos\left(\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right) = 2 \sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2 n^\alpha}\right) < \frac{1}{2 n^{2\alpha}}
$$
Moreover $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2 n^{2 \alpha} u_n = 1$.
Thus the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n$ converges when $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2 \alpha}$ does.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever $\alpha>0$ is, $n^{\alpha} \to \infty$ so $\cos (1/n^{\alpha}) $ will go to $\cos 0 =1$ so $u_n \to 0.$

---

By Taylor expanding, we get $1- \cos(1/n^{\alpha}) = 1/( 2 n^{2\alpha} ) + O( 1/n^{4\alpha}).$ So the sum converges if and only if $\alpha >0.5$.

Comment: But the word used was serie(s), not sequence, so I would guess the question is really about $\sum u_n$.

Comment: Right, I was talking about $\sum u_n$